# Naming convention for exported module variable names

Tags: powershell, variables, module, convention

I have a variable in a module I would like to re-use. Let's say it's a constant.

```
#MyModule.psm1
$MyVar = randomObject
Export-ModuleMember -Variable MyVar

#Get-Stuff.ps1
Import-Module -Name $moduleName
$randomVar = $MyVar.Property
```

I mean, I could just use a regular convention but then how would a coder know this variable was instantiated from an imported module?

Comment: I think this is personal preference. Use something logical and document it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my *opinion* you probably shouldn't be exporting variables to begin with. So far I've not seen a compelling reason to do so.

Instead, I'd rather export a function, even if all it does it return a single object. It's safer, more versatile, more obvious, etc.

But someone importing your module is going to have to know it from reading your documentation or just familiarity with it. It's not as easy as seeing the exported functions.

If you're worried about conflicting names, you have a pretty large latitude in naming your variable, especially if you want to make it really hard to reference:

```
${Some really ___ weird um, variable n@m3} =  randomObject
```

Comment: Now that's *evil* naming.

Comment: @sodawillow oh it gets worse, I just tested a variable name that starts with a space and contains line breaks!

Comment: Now I'm thinking about Zalgo variable names ... *creepy*. I've seen a thread with identifiers written in cyrillic in C#, that was scary too. But I'm getting OT here, sorry. Where is my mind ? ^_^

Comment: @sodawillow yessss now I really want to do that